# VisualSVN is not sorting in alphabetical order

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I'm not sure if this has always been the case, but I noticed it today when I access visual SVN via the browser and could not find the v4.0 tag, when in fact it was there but in the wrong order. Is there some configuration that determines what is used to sort this list?

[image]

Comment: It's called ASCIIbetical order: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCIIbetical_order#Order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion uses case-sensitive sorting in web interface. While you are mixing lower and capital 'V'.

Answer (score 0):

No. Such configuration doesn't exist and VisualSVN Server web-frontend only translated received from WebDAV.

I think (not tested), sort-order is determined by creation of every tag timestamp (or revision number, which is realy the same parameter). You can test it using svn ls -v URL.